# SSH with torify/socks

Tags: torsocks, ssh, torify

I'm having a hard time understanding why torsocks/torify isn't working in this particular case.

```
 torify ssh user@remotemachine
 torsocks ssh user@remotemachine
```

When I do the following command when I get in my actual IP is printed:

```
echo $SSH_CLIENT
# [my actual IP + remote/local ports]
```

But if I do

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -x localhost:9050 %h %p' user@remotemachine # 9050 being the SOCKSPort
```

then I get the tor ip. What gives? What am I missing about how torify/torsocks and/or ssh works?

Contents of torsocks.conf:

```
TorAddress 127.0.0.1
TorPort 9050              # matches tor's SOCKSPort
```

edit: I should mention that I'm on MacOS and cannot torify/torsocks /usr/bin/ssh directly since /usr/bin is protected by Apple's System Integrity Protection so I copy it into /tmp/ssh first. I don't imagine that would change anything but don't know what I don't know so...

Answer (score 1):

From [HowToForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/anonymous-ssh-sessions-with-tor):

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config/`

```
Host anon_*
CheckHostIP no
Compression yes
Protocol 2
ProxyCommand connect -4 -S localhost:9050 $(tor-resolve %h localhost:9050) %p
Host anon_mydomain
HostName mydomain.com
User myaccount
Host anon_mydomain2
HostName mydomain2.com
User myaccount
Port 980
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use full path to your ssh copy like this:

```
torify /tmp/ssh user@remotemachine
torsocks /tmp/ssh user@remotemachine
```

Comment: I do that already. The code I put in my question was the simplest presentation of the problem (perhaps too simplified). I'm not at all familair with Apple's System Integrity Protection system but it prevents binaries in /usr/bin (like curl and ssh) from being used with torify/torsocks.

Comment: I don't know Apple at all but maybe /tmp is not the best choice for exeutables. Have you checked this: https://lorenzo.mile.si/torsocks-macos-is-located-directory-protected-apples-system-integrity-protection/201/?